# Append an item to a list that is stored in a variable with JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this variable:

```
item = "<li>TEXT<ul class='sublist'></ul></li>";
```

Now I want to add `<li>`s to the sublist `<ul>`.

Something like

```
item.('.sublist').append('<li>Sublist item 1</li>');
```

This code, of course, does not work. How should the code like like?

Later I want to add this item to a list:

```
$('#order-list').append(item);
```

Answer (score 2):

Easy, if you add the element to the DOM first:

```
let item = $("<li>TEXT<ul class='sublist'></ul></li>");
$(item).find('ul').append('<li>Sublist item 1</li>');
```

Note, this element does not show up anywhere on the page because it has not been appended to an in-view element.

The drawback, of-course, is that it is no longer a string.

Answer (score 1):

Since `item` is not an html element, you may first transform it to html then insert the desired html there:

```
item = "<li>TEXT<ul class='sublist'></ul></li>";
parsed = $.parseHTML(item); // or, you may simply used $(item)
parsed.find('ul').append('<li>Sublist item 1</li>');
```

And if you want it back to string:

```
parsed.prop('outerHTML')
```

---

Ah, you want this:

> Later I want to add this item to a list:
>
> $('#order-list').append(item);

Then, why don't you simply create element like:

```
sublist = '<li>Sublist item 1</li>';
$('<li />', {
  html: 'TEXT<ul class="sublist">'+sublist+'</ul>'
}).appendTo('#order-list');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to either add that Item to the dom, or if it is already in the dom just select the item and use [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).

This example it is already apart of the dom

```js
let li = document.createElement('li')
li.textContent = 'Sublist item 1'

document.querySelector('.sublist').appendChild(li)
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>TEXT
    <ul class='sublist'></ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

We can use `innerHTML` and pass a string instead of creating an element, but then we can't append things to the `ul`.

```js
document.querySelector('.sublist').innerHTML = '<li>Sublist item 1</li>'
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>TEXT
    <ul class='sublist'></ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

This example we add it to the dom (for simplicity I'm just adding it to the body):

```js
let item = '<ul><li>TEXT<ul class="sublist"></ul></li></ul>'
document.body.innerHTML = item

let li = document.createElement('li')
li.textContent = 'Sublist item 1'

document.querySelector('.sublist').appendChild(li)
```

Answer (score 0):

A pattern that I use to do similar things:

1. create an array of the items you'd like to append

```
var fruits = ["apple", "orange", "banana"]
```

2. get a reference to a DOM element

```
var myList = document.querySelector("#myList")
```

3. use `innerHTML`, `map`, and `join` to wrap an unordered list around your mapped elements and inject it into your DOM reference

```
myList.innerHTML = '<ul>' + 
    items.map(fruit => '<li>' + fruit + '</li>')
.join('') + '</ul>'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a way To do that in one line of code .. using `.end()`

```js
var item = "<li>TEXT<ul class='sublist'></ul></li>";
item = $(item).find('.sublist').append('<li>Sublist item 1</li>').end().prop('outerHTML'); 

$('#order-list').append(item);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="order-list"></ul>
```

<sup>**Explanation**</sup>

```
var item = "<li>TEXT<ul class='sublist'></ul></li>";
item = $(item)
  .find('.sublist')                   // find the sub list
  .append('<li>Sublist item 1</li>')  // append li
  .end()                              // return to the item parent li
  .prop('outerHTML');                 // get outer html

$('#order-list').append(item);        // append to the oreder list
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is not a DOM element. It is a string. In order to create a DOM element you have to either use `document.createElement("ul")` or since you are using jQuery use `$("<ul class="sublist"></ul>)`. Then append the list items. The first one can seem like more work because jQuery abstracts most of the DOM manipulation away.

```
var item = $("<ul class="sublist"></ul>");

//And then 

$(item).append("<li>Sublist item 1</li>");
```

Then you can append that to the DOM.

```
$(body).append(item);
```